# How to check for valid dropbox user session?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, dropbox-api

I am working with the Android Dropbox API. In the main activity of my app, I am doing the auth calls to the dropbox api. The problem is, every time my app launches, the user has to hit "allow" to grant permission for the app to access their dropbox. My code is below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    //clearKeys();
    //Log.e(TAG, "keys cleared");

    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);




    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(Main.this);
    Log.e(TAG, "started authentication");





protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();



    if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // MANDATORY call to complete auth.
            // Sets the access token on the session
            mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

            if(mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()){
            Log.e(TAG, "Authentication finished");
            }
            AccessTokenPair tokens = mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair();

            // Provide your own storeKeys to persist the access token pair
            // A typical way to store tokens is using SharedPreferences
            storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
        }
    }


}//end of onResume()
```

I need to find a way to know that the app is auth'd so I can bypass auth if that is the case. I am not sure how to go about that at this point. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before authentication, check if the stored access token is still valid (if you have one, of course). To do this, simply make an authorized request to any of the methods exposed through OAuth. It is best that you call a method which results in a short, simple output.
If this call fails because of invalid/expired token, proceed to authentication. At this point update the stored token and the rest should work as before

Comment: How to check if stored access token is valid?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal "make an authorized request to any of the methods exposed through OAuth" - I would make a request to https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info and see if I can get an answer

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I am using the Dropbox Core library for android, still i should use api.dropbox.com/1/account/info or do you know any method from the core library that can do the same?

Comment: And can you please tell me how to use api.dropbox.com/1/account/info? I mean which parameters i have to use and should i use GET or POST?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#account-info here is info about using the REST api. If you are using the android lib, you shouldn't need to mess with REST calls though. As soon as you have your DropboxAPI object initialized with your session object(which should contain the token), you shoud call DropboxAPI.accountInfo() in a try/catch to see if the token is ok.

Comment: You should probably edit the above into your answer, as this question comes up as the top Google answer on the topic. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the SDK ?

Sync Api SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/tutorial/android

at *Authenticating to Dropbox:*

> Once this is complete, you should see an info-level message in LogCat
>   saying "Dropbox user  linked." The user only has to do this
>   once, after which the SDK will store the user token in the cache. When
>   your app restarts, you can check whether it is already linked by
>   calling hasLinkedAccount.

**Updated:**

Core API SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/setup#android

Connect Java Doc found here: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/index.html

at *Return to your app after user authorization*:

> The finishAuthentication() method will bind the user's access tokens
>   to the session. You'll now be able to retrieve them via
>   mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair().
>
> You'll need these tokens again after your app closes, so it's
>   important to save them for future access. If you don't, the user will
>   have to re-authenticate every time they access their Dropbox from your
>   app.
>
> A common way to implement storing keys is through Android's
>   SharedPreferences API. To learn how, check out the Android
>   documentation. In the meantime, for simplicity, the code above
>   pretends the storeKeys function invokes whatever method you'd like to
>   use to store your keys in a more permanent location.

**Edit:**

Implementation of storeKeys:

```
public static boolean storeKeys(String key, String secret) {
   SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // this refers to context
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putString("key", key);
   editor.putString("secret", secret);
   return editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: That's for the sync api. I am using the core api. Thanks though.

Comment: Anyone have experience with Event listeners? Could I do this by adding a listener for onCreate somehow?

Comment: the key seems to be `storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);` a method i guess need to implement yourself and use `SharedPreferences` to save these 2 values. So onCreate check if they exist and try to continue to next step, if failure (except no network failures) re-ask for authorization.

Comment: Yeah that was my original question really. What in the world could I check for? There is no documentation on where the token and key are stored. I can throw an if statement in oncreate, but what in the world can I check for? I have no idea where those things are.

Comment: Wait wait wait....I was reading that wrong...I was reading that as storeKeys was already implemented and storing the keys! Hmmm....lemme look at this for a bit.

Comment: it says `retrieve them via mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair()` so i guess this returns the pair. I added implementation of the method and the url for java doc connect it to your IDE it will be helpful!

Comment: Yep....this is the answer....I will post my solution as soon as I get it worked out but mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair() is definitely the right path. Thanks madlymad. Thanks for bearing with me!! You should have said "Hey idiot, you arent reading that right!" :)

Comment: no prob! At first, I haven't understand the what's the problem ;)